# Abinitio- To connect same graph having 2 phases but to run in different database

Tags: ab-initio

Can you please help me to understand how to connect to belonging to different database

1. How can we create have 2 dbc in same environment (Here users are
   different so think it would be easy to have dbc as its same
   server(IP));
2. what if the server are different machine how can we connect same
   abintio instance.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what you are asking. But in general Ab-Initio connects to a database using a driver. For example an Oracle driver. in your DBC file you would reference the tns name of the database. The database can be local or remote, it doesn't matter. The driver establishes the connection as per the tnsnames.ora configuration file.